# Can a server request be routed to a daemon in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon

Yesterday, I have been reading about daemons and considering it for use with a Rails app. I want to have a Ruby server (the daemon) to handle a specific request when it receives one, so it continuously waits for a request in the background (I am not sure whether this will be a proper use case of a daemon, so correct me if I am wrong).

Is there a way to use routes.rb in Rails 5 to route a request to a daemon?

p.s. Please, don't suggest that I should use a standard controller action to handle requests because there is a requirement I need to fulfil that prevented me from using one. Bottom line, I just want that specific request to be handled by a daemon instead of being handled by the main Rails app.

Comment: What do you mean with "a deamon"? the rails server is actually running as a daemon (it's usually run with the `--daemon` option). Do you mean a background process? Can you explain your actual requirement? It's not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: To my understanding, a daemon is also a background process? I am pretty new to all of these. I want to be able to receive updates from a server in real time that will trigger updates to a database. The reason I am not using controller action because there will be a code portion in the main thread blocking to check whether the database has been updated, and Rails won't respond to any other requests (including the request that triggers the database update) while it is checking for updates so I ended up with a never-ending loop. And I thought using a daemon/background process would make sense?

Comment: Check ActiveJob to run background processes https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html. Basically, rails handles the request and the controller first enqueue a background job and returns right away, it does not wait for the job to finish, that way it does not get blocked waiting.